# Unable to resize textbox in Avalonia

Tags: c#, .net, avalonia

Textboxes in Avalonia seem to have fixed height and there is no way they can be resized. At least not any direct means, and I wanted to ask if there are some alternative ways of doing it.

I have a set of rows, and textboxes don't fit there:
[Textboxes too large for rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6IUy.png)

I have tried `Padding`, `Margin`, `MaxHeight`, `Height`, `FontSize`, and displayed height remains unchanged. Margin does work, but only for width.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem today and I found that the only height property that isn't ignored is MinHeight.

If MinHeight is zero (which it is by default) the TextBox appears to be given some arbitrary default height. If it's non-zero, then the TextBox will be that height (even if it should be larger based on contents).